# Sum and difference of independent normal variables are independent?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, both having the standard normal distribution, then are $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ also independent?

To show this, I was trying to get the joint CDF of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ but didn't get far. I know they are individually normally distributed.